# How does iResolution on Panasonic Lumix DMC-GM1 (Micro Four Thirds) work?

Tags: resolution, panasonic, panasonic-lumix

So there's this setting *iResolution* on my Panasonic camera, which allows values *High*, *Standard*, *Low*, *Extended* and *Off*. The manual of the camera doesn't tell me very much about this feature, so I'd like to learn more about it.

What does it do exactly? What are the advantages and disadvantages of this setting? Which situations fit for which setting? When should I turn this on or off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iResolution is just an edge enhancement filter.

- The "i" part in the name implies, like Panasonic's other "i" features, that the camera automatically controls when, and how much, it should apply this feature.  What you select is just the *maximum* amount by which it will do that - it doesn't mean the camera will use it for *every* shot.  Instead it will intelligently decide when to use it.
- The "Resolution" part in the name implies that it's designed to enhance the perceived "resolution" (eg, the resolvability) of your lens or the image as a whole - that is, compensating for any softening in the lens.

It is generally regarded as more useful than most edge enhancement filtering, due to its intelligence (it adjusts itself automatically) and that it's restrained: the effect is quite subtle.

Personally, I leave it off because if an image is softened a little by the lens I either don't mind, or I'm happy to compensate for that in post.  But you may decide you like it left on all the time.

[This dcresource review describes the feature more and shows examples](https://web.archive.org/web/20170525150334/http://www.dcresource.com/reviews/panasonic/dmc_gf3-review/using).  It's about a third of the way down and begins "The Intelligent Resolution feature ..."

Comment: I had been wondering whether the algorithm takes advantage of the fact that the sensor might have more pixels than the final shot (thus combining multiple sensor pixels to one image pixel), specifically when you decide not to use the full sensor resolution. Unfortunately the link is no longer valid; maybe that's why links in answers aren't always a good idea.

Comment: No, the camera should already do that anyway - if you select a lower resolution the camera will downscale using all the source pixels. I've fixed the link by replacing it with an archived version of that now-deactivated site.